# Telegram Bot: Creating Invitation Links and Tracking Statistics

Tags: php, telegram

I have created a Telegram bot using the code provided below. This bot provides users with the ability to generate invitation links for channels and groups. However, I am encountering difficulties in tracking the statistics of these links. I am seeking assistance in modifying the code to enable the tracking of how many invitations each link has attracted to the respective channel or group. The ultimate goal is to display this data on a dashboard.

```
<?php

$botToken = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN';
$groupId = 'YOUR_GROUP_ID';

function createGroupInviteLink($botToken, $groupId) {
    $telegramApiUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $botToken . '/';
    $method = 'exportChatInviteLink';
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $groupId
    ];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($telegramApiUrl . $method, false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($result['ok']) {
        return $result['result'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getJoinCountByInviteLink($botToken, $inviteLink) {
    $telegramApiUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $botToken . '/';
    $method = 'getChatMemberCount';
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $inviteLink
    ];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($telegramApiUrl . $method, false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($result['ok']) {
        return $result['result'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage example
$inviteLink = createGroupInviteLink($botToken, $groupId);
if ($inviteLink) {
    echo 'Group invite link: ' . $inviteLink;
} else {
    echo 'Failed to create the invite link.';
}

// Usage example
$inviteLink = 'YOUR_INVITE_LINK';
$joinCount = getJoinCountByInviteLink($botToken, $inviteLink);
if ($joinCount) {
    echo 'Number of members joined via invite link: ' . $joinCount;
} else {
    echo 'Failed to retrieve the join count.';
}

?>
```

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.